# How should a BigCommerce app authenticate with a 3rd party API?

Tags: bigcommerce

We are building a BigCommerce app to interface with our SaaS product.

After installing the app, the user needs to authenticate with our service.  Unless BigCommerce offers some SSO solution, this means they'll enter an email/password to login.  This will return an access token for our API.

Does BigCommerce have some kind of storage to hold this token?  I don't want users to have to re-authenticate any time they access our app admin view from a different computer or as a different user.

Is there an SSO for apps? I'm only seeing customer SSO.  I also don't see anything about settings/token storage.

Comment: Hi Harry, have you seen the new changelog updates to BC data hooks? https://github.com/bigcommerce/storefront-data-hooks/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, there was an update that helps resolve this issue: https://github.com/bigcommerce/storefront-data-hooks/issues/11 which may relate to what youre asking.

Comment: Hi @HeatherBarr, I had not! To be clear, can this SSO be used by app developers to authenticate the store owners that have our app installed?  It seemed like this SSO was just for authenticating customers of a store. Hopefully that makes sense.

Without SSO, the flow for our app would be: store owner installs app, store owner views it in their admin dashboard, store owner enters an email/password to authenticate with our platform.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Harry. That does make sense to me, thanks for clarifying! 
This thread may be helpful -- it is a different use case, however it may be helpful with getting to a point where you can make api calls within your app. 
https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D54O00006p2QODSA2/how-to-place-an-api-call-from-within-a-bc-app

In reference to the token storage, BigCommerce doesn't store access tokens, rather you have to get an access token to interface with BigCommerce's APIs. So you may need to go about this in a different direction to get the result you're seeking. :)